# Run part of function once, but run rest of function every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that checks the status of connection to server. I want to run checkOnline every 5 seconds. If the connection is lost, and it keeps failing then the fadeIn for error message keeps running as well (creates a flashing effect). How can I change it so that the fade functions are only run once, when it fails, but still keeps checking the connection.

```
$(function () {

var url = 'https://examplesite.com/';

function checkOnline() {
    $.get(url).done(function () {
        window.location = url;
    }).fail(function () {
        $('.errortext').hide().fadeIn(500);
        $('.loadingtext').fadeOut(500);
    });
};

window.setInterval(function () { checkOnline(); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function () { checkOnline(); }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: Set a variable that says "I have already shown an error message" to `true` after the first time. Don't perform that logic when the variable is already `true`.

Comment: Assuming connectivity is present, it looks like you are reloading the page or re-visiting `url` every 5 seconds. Is that the intended behaviour? I ask cuz if it's not then you need to handle the case when connectivity is resumed after a loss.

Comment: Right, every 5 seconds it 'pings' the server to make sure there is a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of whether the fade effects already ran. Then check it before running the fade. Here's an example that uses a variable called fadeFlag:

```
var fadeFlag = false;

function fadeOnce() {
    // Has fade happened already?
    if (fadeFlag === false) {
        // No. Then do the effects
        $('.errortext').hide().fadeIn(500);
        $('.loadingtext').fadeOut();
        fadeFlag = true;
    }
}

function checkOnline() {
    $.get(url).done(function () {
        window.location = url;
    }).fail(function () {
        // Try the fade effects
        fadeOnce();
    });
};
```

The first time `fadeOnce()` is called, it runs the effects and then sets `fadeFlag` to `true`. The next time, it sees that `fadeFlag` is `true`, so it does nothing.